# memory leak when using base64 images

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, google-chrome-extension, base64

I'm creating extension something similar to speed dial form.
It creates new tab page with image thumbnails.
 [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/6xzpmd) for better understanding

Those images are read from an array of base64 datauri.
In html, I have container `div` in which I'm creating thumbnails from array loop. I've been trying different approaches to accomplish small(reasonable) memory usage, but without of luck.

this is one

```
 chrome.storage.local.get('imgArray', function (result) {
    var imgArray = result.imgArray;

    var cnt = document.createElement('div');
    cnt.id = 'contaier';
    cnt.style.left = l+'px';
    cnt.style.bottom = 0+'px';
    cnt.style.width = l2+'px';
    document.body.appendChild(cnt); 

    for (var i=0, l=imgArray.length; i<l; i++) {
        var sp = document.createElement('div');
        sp.id = lv.id;
        sp.className = 'thumbNail';
        cnt.appendChild(sp);
        sp.setAttribute("style", "background-image: url('" + imgArray[i].ss2 + "');");  

        /* other minor elements.... not important*/
    }

    imgArray=null;
});
```

Every time I resize window, memory jumps in step of 10-20MB, and that accumulates very fast, so I can easily get 400-500MB memory usage for 20-25 small image previews.

I did played with different img sizes upon very creation of thumbnails, so I have images in approx. 1000x500px *(imgArray[i].ss)* and 500x250px *(imgArray[i].ss2)*
Smaller images do consume less memory (not much) but still, mem. accumulation is the same...

another approach with canvas, to avoid bg-image:

```
for (var i=0, l=imgArray.length; i<l; i++) {
    (function(lv) {
        var sp = document.createElement('div');
        sp.id = lv.id;
        sp.className = 'thumbNail';
        cnt.appendChild(sp);

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.className = 'stImg';

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


        var img = new Image;
        img.onload = function(){
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        };
        img.src = lv.ss2;       

        sp.appendChild(canvas);     

    }(imgArray[i]));        
}
```

I tried also with img element too, inside thumbnail div.
Nulling original array helps a little but that is not a real problem.
I have to use base64 images, and basically every redrawing of DOM eats memory and never release it....

Is there a way to keep memory usage low?
or some technique to avoid redrawing (if that is actual problem in the first place)...

Comment: Could you add a minimal example that demonstrates the problem? This question looks interesting, but without a way to quickly reproduce the problem I won't bother looking into the issue for the lack of time.

Comment: I'will try to make something, but only as extension example ...I can't recreate that as jsfiddle or something

Comment: I had serious issues exporting more than 15-16 thumbnails as default data for installing this extension. Extension crashed every time...here it is..
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By0ST0eW-ZW9UnRqZURTc2s0ZmM/view?usp=sharing  click on blue icon to start it...try resizing window and observe memory consumption...in my case every resize easts about 15MB

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm using Opera developer...but it is the same situation in Chrome Canary

Comment: I don't see anything extraordinary... Indeed, upon resizing the memory usage shoots up, but eventually (after a few (tens of) seconds), the memory is released again.

Comment: I just tested it on Chrome Stable (x32), Canaray (x64), Opera developer (x32) ..Only Chrome stable behaves in that way, release memory on GC cycles...Canary and O-dev (based on 43.0.2351.3) never do..at least on my end